# MySQL Server wont start on MAMP/AMPPS/XAMPP after updating to mac High Sierra 10.13.2

Tags: macos, xampp, mamp, macos-high-sierra

I'm desperate.. I updated to mac High Sierra 10.13.2 and my MySQL wouldn't start on my MAMP:

[image]

So I deleted the ib_logfileN:s, typed **sudo killall mysqld** in terminal and restarted MAMP(that usually works)

[image]

but it didn't. So in the end I had to uninstall MAMP and download it again - and it worked the first time, but when I restarted it, same problem. So I uninstalled MAMP - downloaded AMPPS - and the same problem appeared there. So uninstalled AMPPS and downloaded XAMPP, and the same problem appeared there:

[image]

.. Obviously there is something wrong with my MySQL Server that I cant figure out, i want to murder my computer. Any help or guideance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you provide some log? Just thinking about port conflict...

Comment: Trying to figure out how to access the log .. Sorry I'm very new at this - what do I enter in terminal to get error log? @VoldedoreMKD

Comment: On your screenshot, click to the `Application log` and check if there are any mysql log. If not, then try to look for it in `/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err` (see [this](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/09/how-to-show-your-mamp-logs-within.html), the info is a bit old so I'm not sure it's still the same for now)

Comment: @VoldedoreMKD In the end I removed mysql from my computer with homebrew and re installed it, now it works. Tanks <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to uninstall mysql with homebrew, and reinstall it according to: https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks. It has worked after that.